# "attempt to index a nil value (field '?')"

Tags: lua

What I do wrong, I know that there are issues with `nil` in table but:

```
local did = gwaExtractFromTopic(2)
local measurementId = gwaData.id
local newMessage = gwaData.value
local topic = gwaExtractFromTopic(2)


if did ~= nil and measurementId ~= nil then
    table[did][measurementId] = newMessage
end
```

Still in the code I got `attempt to index a nil value (field '?')`

**EDIT:** I have changed the source code, but still does not work:

```
local measurements[did] = {}

if did and measurementId and tab[did] then
    measurements[did][measurementId] = newMessage
end
```

Comment: `table` are the "container" type in Lua, reserved

Comment: changed the name and I see the same issue

Comment: try so check `if  did  and measurementId  and tab[did]  then ...` - tab[did]  must exist

Comment: @Mike V, no, `table` is just a global variable and can be overridden (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1).

Comment: @Mike V, correct: before assigning `table[did][measurementId]`, you shuld assign `table[did]` to a table. Until this is done, `table[did]` is nil. @Mike V should post this as an answer.

Comment: @Mike V, although meddling with *global* `table`, rather that with a local variable with the same name, will have side effects.

Comment: I have changed code, but still, does not work ;-(

Comment: And where is `tab` initialised to a table. so that it can have `[did]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local measurements[did] = {}
```

`measurements[did]` indexes the `did` field in the table `measurements`

You cannot use an expression as a variable name. Also as measurements is nil in the provided code you get an error for indexing a nil value.

Try something like this:

```
local measurements = {}

if did and measurementId then
  measurements[did] = {}
  measurements[did][measurementId] = newMessage
end
```